# How to cause locks to be freed in one thread which were set by another

Tags: locking, pthreads, mutex, threadpool

I have a simple thread pool written in pthreads implemented using a pool of locks so I know which threads are available. Each thread also has a condition variable it waits on so I can signal it to do work.

When work comes in, I pick a thread by looking finding an available thread from the lock pool. I then set a data structure associated with the thread that contains the work it needs to do and signal on the condition variable that the thread should start working.

The problem is when the thread completes work. I need to unlock the thread in the lock pool so it's available for more work. However, the controlling thread is the one which set the lock, so the thread can't free this lock itself. (And the controlling thread doesn't know when work is done.)

Any suggestions?

*I could rearchitect my thread pool to use a queue where all threads are signaled when work is added so one thread can grab it. However, in the future, thread affinity will likely be a problem for incoming work and the lock pool makes implementation of this easier.*

Comment: Using the pthreads API is it possible to determine the run state of a particular thread e.g. whether the thread has completed it's work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the piece of data that you're trying to synchronize access to is the free/busy status of each thread.

So, have a table (array) that records the free/busy status of each thread, and use a mutex to protect access to that table. Any thread (controller or worker) that wants to examine/change the thread status needs to seize the mutex, but the lock needs to be held only while the status is being examined/changed, not for the entire duration of the thread's work.

To assign work to a thread, you would do:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_status_table_lock);
-- search table for available thread
-- assign work to that thread
-- set thread status to "busy"
pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_status_table_lock);
-- signal the thread
```

And when the thread finishes its work, it would change its status back to "free":

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_status_table_lock);
-- set thread status to "free"
pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_status_table_lock);
```

Comment: This basically answered my question. I realized there is a fundamental flaw in the way I implemented my pool. Instead of having a set of locks for each item in the pool, I should have a single lock and then a set of status variables. This is likely to be much more efficient as well.

Thanks!